# Microsoft Graph encoding GZIP

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get more quickly response from the following Microsoft Graph API calling:

```cs
string filter = $"start/dateTime ge '{start.ToString("o")}' and start/dateTime le '{end.ToString("o")}'";
Timer.Start();
ICalendarEventsCollectionPage pageCollection = await _client.GraphServiceClient
    .Users[userPrincipalNameOrId]
    .Calendar
    .Events
    .Request()
    .OrderBy("start/dateTime")
    .Filter(filter)
    .Top(250)
    .Header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
    .GetAsync();

if (pageCollection != null && pageCollection.Count > 0)
{
    // my code
}
```

I use 250 on top for avoid using next page calling(), I tried to use also header with accept encoding gzip for optimize the network transmission time, but I don't see any time reduction ..

For 126 events the time was 3740 ms.

Are there any parameter existing for data sending compression, because I want to reduce the load time?

Comment: It may be good idea to include size of response into the question. Presumably it in megabytes as you hope compression will speed up networking part of the request (include resulting size when you manually zip the response)... I personally doubt that compression would have any measurable effect on "give me list of calendar items" request.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that compressing the results will actually reduce the time taken? That would only be the case if the bottleneck is in network transmission. (And of course there's a tiny bit of time taken to do the compression and decompression.) How large is the data for the 126 events?

Comment: If you need only a subset of properties you can use .Select and specify these properties. It will reduce the size of the response and it should increase the response time. You can also perform ordering by start/dateTime on the client.